# Transmit Data to Police Scanner through android app

Tags: android

I want to transmit data to Police Scanner through my android application. Is it possible to do so? I am new to android development,please help me out.

Comment: Are you making this for the police?

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more exact on both devices involved. If the scanner has a bluetooth / IR receiver then possibly with a standard (ish) phone. Otherwise I suspect you'll need some sort of USB interface and that will depend entirely on drivers for android being available.

Comment: @RohitNavarathna : Yes I am making this for police

Comment: @PallaviUdawant Ok, we will believe it for now...